# Distribution of numbers from a cyclic group $Z_p$

Tags: group-theory, probability-distributions, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

Let assume, that I have a group of prime order $p-1$ denoted as $Z_p$. 
From this group I generate randomly two sets of numbers: 
$\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\}$ and $\{y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5\}$ and compute values $$m_{1} = \prod_{i=1}^{5} x_i$$ and $$m_{2} = \prod_{i=1}^{5} y_i.$$ 
Let's now assume that I now the values of numbers: $x_1, x_3, x_4$ and $y_1, y_3, y_5$ but I don't know the values of $x_2, x_4, y_2, y_4$. Given all these information, with what probability I can distinguish the values $m_1$ and $m_2$ from values $m_1' = x_1\cdot y_2 \cdot x_3 \cdot y_4 \cdot x_5$ and $m_2' = y_1\cdot x_2 \cdot y_3 \cdot x_4 \cdot y_5$ respectively.

Does the chance of distinguishing these values depends on the size of the group?

Can I somehow describe the distribution of a number which I am randomly taking from the cyclic group?

Comment: your multiplication .. it is in which ring/ group ? why not use the addition in $\mathbb{Z}/ n \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 In group

Comment: @user1952009 Can you write a full post explaining what you mean? I what to consider a case exactly how I described

Comment: the group $(\mathbb{Z}/ (p-1) \mathbb{Z},+)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/ p \mathbb{Z},\times)$, while the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ has an additive and a multiplicative group... so it is not clear what is the multiplication you use in $m_1 = \prod x_i$

Comment: @user1952009 I am talking about (ℤ/pℤ,×), a multiplicative group (group mod p) not about a field

Comment: so why not talk about $(\mathbb{Z}/ (p-1) \mathbb{Z},+)$ instead !!! it is the same. they are isomorphic $m_1' = \sum x_i'$

Comment: @user1952009 If you know, how to solve this for Z/(p-1)Z, can you show and explain how this is similar to my problem? And I will be able to tell if I understand and agree or not

Comment: your problem becomes trivial as every elements are invertible... the probability to find $x_1 , x_2$ from $x_1 + x_2$ is $1/(p-1)$